# Django admin - Custom change_form.html and 3rd party apps custom change_form

Tags: django, templates

I am currently customizing the admin templates of my models and I ran into an issue with ModelAdmin that inherits of 3rd party ones like django-importexport or django-modelclone.

Both of these apps come either with their `change_list.html` or `change_form.html`. Each of them extends either `admin/change_list.html` or `admin/change_form.html`.

So my Model admin looks like this :

```
class MyModelAdmin(SuitObjectActionsMixin, ImportExportModelAdmin, ClonableModelAdmin):
```

I tried to customise my ModelAdmin with adding the file `change_form.html` into `/templates/myapp/mymodel/`. I know that should work as it does for another admin that doesn't inherit from any 3rd party apps.

Using the debug toolbar, it appears that the template used is the one of `django-modelclone` that extends the standard `change_form.html` and not the one I created.

It seems that 3rd party apps templates override any "local" custom template just by extending the standard one.

Is there a clean way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify change form template and change list template in your ModelAdmin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(A, B, C):
    change_form_template = 'path/to/my_change_form.html'
    change_list_template = 'path/to/my_change_list.html'
```

That one worked for me in similar situation.

Comment: It's good if you want to totally override the templates but not in my case.

For example, `django-modelclone` simply add a action button in its `change_form.html` and I still want this button in my custom template.

Comment: If you mean admin actions, you will have that if you put your own template. If it's something more complex, you can copy html template of modelclone or other battery and customize it. I did that with grappelli for example.

Comment: forgot to reply sorry...

It ended up by doing what you suggested, adding the HTML for the 3rd party apps directly into the template